# sudo in non-interactive script

Tags: shell-script, sudo

I have a script that executes three functions: `A && B && C`.

Function `B` needs to be run as a super-user, while `A` and `C` don't.

I have several solutions but neither of these are satisfying:

1. sudo the entire script: `sudo 'A && B && C'`

   That seems like a bad idea to run `A` and `C` as super-user if it's not
   needed
2. make the script interactive: `A && sudo B && C`

   I might have to type-in my password, but I want my script to be
   non-interactive, as each function can take some time, and I don't want
   the script to wait for me. Well, that's also why it's a script in the
   first place, so I don't have to watch it run.
3. The stupid solution: `sudo : && A && sudo -n B && C`

   First it seems stupid to run a no-op `sudo` first, and also I must cross
   my finger that A is not going to take more than `$sudo_timeout`.
4. Hypothetical solution (I wish you tell me it exists):

   `sudo --store-cred 'A && sudo --use-cred-from-parent-sudo B && C'`

   That would prompt for my password at the beginning, and then use that
   credentials only when needed.

What's your opinion on all this? I'd be very surprised that there is no
solution to that problem, as I think it's a pretty common problem (what
about `make all && sudo make install`)

Comment: You could make a script that you execute with sudo, but in the script execute the `A` and `C` parts explicitly using `su -l some_non_priviliged_user`. No timeout issues, and no priveliges for A and C. I don't think that 4 is possible, `sudo` seems a "global state" for a user.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the best thing that you can do is launch the script with `sudo` and then launch the processes you want to run as a normal user explicitly with `su user` or `sudo -u user`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

## Detect the user who launched the script
usr=$(env | grep SUDO_USER | cut -d= -f 2)

## Exit if the script was not launched by root or through sudo
if [ -z $usr ] && [ $UID -ne 0 ]
then
    echo "The script needs to run as root" && exit 1
fi

## Run the job(s) that don't need root
sudo -u $usr commandA

## Run the job that needs to be run as root
commandB
```

Comment: Should the second condition be `$USER != "root"`?

Comment: Indeed it should, @MikePartridge, thanks. I changed it to use `UID`, which is better since you can actually change the name of the root account.

Answer (score 9):

Add your script to the `/etc/sudoers` file with the `NOPASSWD` attribute, so that it is permitted to run without prompting for a password. You can tie this down to a specific user (or set of users), or allow it to be run with `sudo` by anyone on your system.

A sample line for a script called `/usr/local/bin/bossy` might look something like this

```
ALL ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/bossy
```

And you'd then use something like this

```
A && sudo bossy && C
```

For this example I assumed `PATH` includes `/usr/local/bin`. If not, then just use the full path to the script, i.e. `sudo /usr/local/bin/bossy`

Comment: Upvote for the most secure approach.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the `!requiretty` option in `sudo` as well as the `NOPASSWD` option. But keep in mind this reduces security.

Comment: As the problem is defined as not wanting the script to be interactive, #2 with `/etc/sudoers` entry for the user to execute  command `B` with `NOPASSWD` is the right answer.

Comment: That's "you could do X or Y", it was "you could do X and Y". Only both will solve the problem. Perhaps I should re-word my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Building on my answer
to [Pre-authorize sudo? (So it can be run later)](https://superuser.com/q/640491/150988),
write two scripts:

- `ABC_script`:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  sudo -b ./B_script
  A  &&  > A_is_done
  while [ ! -f B_is_done ]
  do
          sleep 60
  done
  rm -f B_is_done
  C
  ```
- `B_script`:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  while [ ! -f A_is_done ]
  do
          sleep 60
  done
  rm -f A_is_done
  B  &&  > B_is_done
  ```

Run `./ABC_script`:

- It will run `sudo -b ./B_script`. 
  This asks for the password (*immediately* after you run `ABC_script`). 
  Assuming that the correct password is entered,
  it spawns `B_script` in the **b**ackground (because `-b` was specified) as root. 
  This seems to be equivalent to `sudo sh -c "./B_script &"`.
- `B_script` starts running asynchronously, in parallel with `ABC_script`. 
  `B_script` tests for the existence of a file called `A_is_done`
  and loops until it appears.
- In parallel, `ABC_script` runs `A`. 
  If/when `A` finishes successfully, the script creates a file called `A_is_done`.
- `ABC_script` then tests for the existence of a file called `B_is_done`
  and loops until it appears.
- In parallel,
  `B_script` detects the existence of `A_is_done` and breaks out of the loop. 
  It deletes the `A_is_done` file and runs `B`. 
  Remember, `B_script` is running as root, so it runs `B` as root. 
  If/when `B` finishes successfully,
  the script creates a file called `B_is_done` and exits.
- In parallel,
  `ABC_script` detects the existence of `B_is_done` and breaks out of the loop. 
  It deletes the `B_is_done` file. 
  Remember, `B_script` ran as root, so `B_is_done` is owned by root,
  and you want to use `rm -f` to avoid getting a request for confirmation.
  `ABC_script` then runs `C` and exits.

Notes for further refinement:

- `ABC_script` should probably run `B_script` by an absolute path rather than `./`.
- Rather than `A_is_done` and `B_is_done`,
  `ABC_script` should probably generate random, unique filenames.
- There needs to be a provision for the script that is spin-waiting
  to be notified if the program that it is waiting for has finished but failed. 
  (Right now, if `A` fails, both scripts just go into an infinite wait loop.) 
  This could be as simple as changing

  ```
  A  &&  > A_is_done
  ```

  to

  ```
  A; echo $? > A_is_done
  ```

  and then modifying the spin-waits to read the `X_is_done` files,
  and proceed if it contains 0 and exit otherwise.

Answer (score -3):

Be dumb. use many lines.

```
if A; then

    if sudo B ; then
        C
    fi
fi
```

Comment: how is that solving any of my concern? The problem has nothing to do with `&&`

Comment: && stops execution when the first command fails. The if statements do this more verbosely. My point is to get your work done, even if it isn't pretty.

Comment: This is nothing more than a more verbose version of option 2: `A && sudo B && C`. Just as Antoine explains in the question; this doesn't ask for the password until `A` has finished, and he doesn't want to have to wait for that, or have the script wait for him.