# How do I maintain sudo in a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, permissions, sudo

If I run this script, how do I pass super user permissions to it? I wrote this just to setup new machines with the basics. I don't want to run every command with elevated permissions, but the commands that do have `sudo` I want to run with them.

How do I have some commands run with `sudo` and others run as the regular user?

```
#!/bin/sh

# If Linux, install nodeJS
if $(uname) = 'Linux';
then
    export IS_LINUX=1
    # Does it have aptitude?
    if  -x "which apt-get";
    then
        export HAS_APT=1
        # Install NodeJS
        sudo apt-get install --yes nodejs
    fi
    # Does it have yum?
    if  -x "which yum" ;
    then
        export HAS_YUM=1
        # Install NodeJS
        sudo yum install nodejs npm
    fi
    # Does it have pacman?
    if  -x "which pacman" ;
    then
        export HAS_PACMAN=1
        # Install NodeJS
        pacman -S nodejs npm
    fi
fi

# If OSx, install Homebrew and NodeJS
if  $(uname) = 'Darwin' ;
then
    export IS_MAC=1
    if test ! "$(which brew)"
    then
      echo "================================"
      echo "  Installing Homebrew for you."
      echo "================================"
      ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
      export HAS_BREW=1
    elif  -x 'which brew' ;
    then
      export HAS_BREW=1
      brew update
    fi
    # Install NodeJS
    brew install --quiet node
fi

# Does it have python?
if  -x "which python" ;
then
    export HAS_PYTHON=1
    if  -x "which pip" ;
    then
      pip list --outdated | cut -d ' ' -f1 | xargs -n1 pip install -U
      export HAS_PIP=1
    fi
fi
# Does it have node package manager?
if  -x "which npm" ;
then
    export HAS_NPM=1
else
    echo "NPM install failed, please do manually"
fi
# Does it have ruby gems?
if  -x "which gem" ;
then
    export HAS_GEM=1
fi
```

The rest of the bash script (that I didn't include for length) installs packages from an array using npm, apt, yum, brew, or pacman, depending on the machine. It only installs simple things like `git`, `wget`, etc.

Comment: Related:  [sudo in non-interactive script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/190571/80216).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First time `sudo` is invoked password is prompted for. Then, depending on configuration, if invoked within N minutes (default 5 minutes IIRC), one do not need to enter password again.

You could do something like:

```
sudo echo >/dev/null || exit 1
```

or perhaps something like:

```
sudo -p "Become Super: " printf "" || exit 1
```

at start of script.

If you want to prevent anyone from doing `sudo ./your_script` you should check EUID as well (*bash*):

```
if [[ $EUID -eq 0 ]]
then
    printf "Please run as normal user.\n" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

or something like:

```
if [ "$(id -u)" = "0" ]
   ...
```

In any case also check out which shell you targetr. I.e.

- https://wiki.debian.org/DashAsBinSh
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh
- https://lwn.net/Articles/343924/

etc.

---

To *"keep it alive"* one could do [something like](https://serverfault.com/q/266039/149447):

```
while true; do
  sleep 300
  sudo -n true
  kill -0 "$$" 2>/dev/null || exit
done &
```

Comment: Great idea! How do I then allow only some parts of the bash script to run as `sudo` and others to run as a normal user? While maintaining the ability to use `sudo` without it timing out?

Comment: @Tyler.Exposure: Expanded a bit. You *allow* any command to be run as `sudo` by prepending it by `sudo` ... I might not get what you are asking.

Comment: Awesome, ok I think sleep -n works!!! Thank you!!!